# APEX PWA keep running in phones background

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I need a way for my apex application that i've turned into a PWA to keep syncing the person location in the background even if the application is closed any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it in Apex. It is a front-end application, it can't work when it is not working (am I smart or what?).

I'd suggest you to move that "syncing" process into the database. Way to do it regularly is to **schedule** it as a database job. Use `DBMS_SCHEDULER` (or older `DBMS_JOB`) package to do that. For example:

```
begin
  dbms_scheduler.create_job (
    job_name    => 'sync_person_location',
    job_type    => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action  => 'BEGIN p_synchronize; end;',
    start_date  => to_timestamp_tz ('30.01.2021 02:00 Europe/Zagreb',
                                    'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi TZR'),
    repeat_interval  => 'FREQ=DAILY; BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI; BYHOUR=8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16; BYMINUTE=5',
    enabled     => true,
    comments    => 'Sync every 5 minutes during work hours from MON to FRI');
end;
/
```

In Apex, refreshing the page (report?) would show new data database job prepared.

Comment: but if i were to do that how would i be able to get the persons location because im currently using a plugin into apex that gets the persons latitude and longitude through a dynamic action and then it stores it into a page item

Comment: I don't know your data model and don't know what plug-in does. If possible, store latitude and longitude into the database (which means that you'd probably skip the plug-in entirely) and fetch that information directly from the table (you can still use dynamic action for that).

Comment: The plug-in is basically just getting the devices latitude and longitude